# On delete I want to redirect to the previous page in rails (using Kaminari gem to pagination)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect to just before page when i delete an item from current page . (ie; if suppose total 3 pages, and if i delete 1 item it should redirect to 2nd page). but iam getting this error.

[image]

please give me a solution

this is my 
  `accounts_controller.rb`

```
def customisations
  @customises = @user.customised_dresses.all.order(id: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(1)
end
```

this is my `accounts/customisations.slim.html`

```
if @customises
- if @customises.empty?
You have no items in your list
   = link_to 'Customise Dress', :customise_index, class: 'btn btn-primary'
- else - @customises.each_slice(3) do |row|
      .row
        - row.each do |c|
              = image_tag c.image_url(:preview)
                  a href="#{customised_dress_path(:id => c.id)}" data-method ="delete" rel="nofollow"
                    i.icon.ion-trash-b
                    |Delete 
   = paginate @customises`
```

this is my 'customised_dress_controller.rb`

```
def destroy
@customised_dresses = CustomisedDress.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:id]).first
  respond_to do |format|
    if @customised_dresses.present?
      @customised_dresses.destroy
      last_page = @customises.total_pages
      format.html redirect_to:customisations_account(page: last_page), notice: "Customised dress has been successfully destroyed" 
    else
      format.html redirect_to:customisations_account(page: last_page), notice: 'You have no customised item.' 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You didn't defined `@customises` in `destroy` method, so this `last_page = @customises.total_pages` fails.

Comment: @customises is defined in my accounts controller

Answer (score 0):

In your class, define an [attr_accessor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) for `customises` attribute:

```
attr_accessor :customises
```

Then, it would work.

It's currently failing because you did not declare `customises` instance variable inside your `destroy` method. You declared it in the `customisations` method but want to access from being in the `destroy` method.

Or, alternatively, you could just call the `customisations` method in place of `@customises` in your `destroy` method. That would work too. So, you can change this line:

```
last_page = @customises.total_pages
```

to:

```
last_page = customisations.total_pages
```

This should fix your problem. If not, let me know! I can update my answer after getting your feedback.

#### Update after getting feedback from you:

I think, when you call `customised_dress_path` method in your view, you need to pass the `@customises` as a param to your `customised_dress_controller` so that it can have access to it.

Something like:

```
customised_dress_path(:id => c.id, :customises => @customises)
```

Then, in your `customised_dress_controller`'s `destroy` method grab it:

```
@customises = params[:customises]
```

That way, your `@customises` will not be `nil` anymore in your `destroy` method.

Comment: check my code once again. onclicking customisations it goes to customised_dress_controller, there it does destroy. but page is coming from accounts_controller. so that anything i declared in my customised_dress_controller shows error

Comment: So, I think, when you call `customised_dress_path` method in your view, you need to pass the `@customises` as a param to your `customised_dress_controller` so that it can have access to it. Something like: `customised_dress_path(:id => c.id, :customises => @customises)`

Comment: do you have this app on github so that I can take a look and see whats wrong with it?

Comment: If yes, then this is my github: https://github.com/rakibulislam
Add me as a collaborator. I will take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87224/discussion-between-sreena-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).